# What is the use of MYSQL8 variable 'character_set_database'?

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

I use the SQL 'show variables like 'character%';' to show the character set in MySQL variables.I find a variable named 'character_set_database', I want to know the use of it. I get some info from the MySQL doc website. But I don't know the mean of 'default database' in the doc context. The keyword 'default database' makes me confused about the use of the variable 'character_set_database'.
So please help me to explain the keyword '**default database**' or the use of variable '**character_set_database**' directly.

The desc about attribute '**character_set_database**' in mysql website:

> **·** character_set_database
>
> The character set used by the **default database**. The server sets this variable whenever the **default database** changes. If there is no default database, the variable has the same value as character_set_server.
>
> As of MySQL 8.0.14, setting the session value of this system variable is a restricted operation. The session user must have privileges sufficient to set restricted session variables. See Section 5.1.9.1, “System Variable Privileges”.
>
> The global character_set_database and collation_database system variables are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of MySQL.
>
> Assigning a value to the session character_set_database and collation_database system variables is deprecated and assignments produce a warning. The session variables will become read-only in a future version of MySQL and assignments will produce an error. It will remain possible to access the session variables to determine the database character set and collation for the default database."

The reference link : [character_set_database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_database)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote with credit from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. PS Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I have revised my question.

Comment: This is still not clear. You quote an explanation. Why are you asking for another one? Where are you stuck in that one? In what way are you stuck understanding this term or using this term? What does the body of your post have to do with the title? What exactly is your question? How are you stuck answering your question?

Comment: @philipxy I want to know the use of 'character_set_database' variable.

Comment: That doesn't address my comments. Good luck. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy Please ignore the previous comment. I want to know the use of the 'character_set_database' variable. So I search it in the Mysql website. But the website description of it makes me confused. I don't know the meaning of the 'default database'  in the description context so I can't make sense of the use of 'character_set_database'. Maybe my question title is not clear enough while I can't revise the title again now, so sorry.

Comment: @philipxy I have revised my question description. My English is poor, I have tried my best to make my question clear. Thanks.

Comment: In computer science/programming, a "default" value in a situation is a value that is used when no other value is given in that situation. PS I tried to help you, but I still don't know what your problem is. Don't ask us to rewrite documentation. Explain about how you are stuck. https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2F+%22database%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`character_set_database`** variable shows you the default character set of the database which is currently in *use*. To select a default database you use:

```
use my_database;
```

Consider the following example..

Create two new databases with different character sets:

```
create database test_db1 character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci;
create database test_db2 character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Now select a database and see what's in the `character_set_database` variabale:

```
use test_db1;
select @@character_set_database;
```

Will return: `'latin1'`

```
use test_db2;
select @@character_set_database;
```

Will return: `'utf8mb4'`

The default character set of a database is used for new tables, when you don't specify it explicitly. Example:

```
use test_db2;

create table test1 (c text) default character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci;
show create table test1;

create table test2 (c text);
show create table test2;
```

The first result will be:

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `c` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

As you can see, the table `test1` is using `CHARSET=latin1`, which we have set explicitly.

The second result will be:

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `c` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Since we didn't specify the character set for the table `test2`, it is using `CHARSET=utf8mb4`, which is the default character set of the database `test_db2`. And `test_db2` is currently the ***default database***, since we have selcted it with `use test_db2`. It is called *default databse*, because it's used, when you omit the the database prefix in statement.

Example:

```
select * from test_db1.test1;
```

will return the same as

```
use test_db1;
select select * from test1;
```